# Is it kosher to memory map a file a second time but with a larger size?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-mapped-files

In my application, one file on disk is created and memory mapped with an initial size. If I apply a second memory mapping to the file, with a larger size, the file expands to the new size. Windows lets me do this without error but I don't know if it's actually kosher. Are there any problems with a second memory mapping with a larger size?

Comment: You question is if there is a problem with having same memory mapped twice in a single process or are you worried about something more?

Comment: The question is if it's okay to have a second mapping with a larger size than the first one. I'll clarify the question.

Comment: No, I don't think a Rabbi will approve.

Comment: @MarkRansom, says the (language) agnostic. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation has this to say:

> After a file mapping object is created, the size of the file must not exceed the size of the file mapping object; if it does, not all of the file contents are available for sharing.

This would appear to imply (since no other downsides or prohibitions are mentioned) that the only side effect of mapping a file a second time with a larger size is that the first mapping won't be able to see the whole thing (obviously).